# Why is type checking in case throwing warning

Tags: scala

I'm trying to check if all the values in the map are of type Plant. I know that there are better ways of doing this. But I'm trying to understand match and I want to know why this wouldn't work. What is the mistake I'm making here.

Why is there a warning. ab2 has all plants, but why doesn't it return true?

```
 abstract class Living
  abstract class Animal extends Living
  abstract class Plant extends Living

  case class Dog() extends Animal
  case class Hibiscus() extends Plant
  case class Apple() extends Plant

  val ab1  = Map(1 -> Dog, 2 -> Hibiscus)
  val ab2  = Map(1 -> Apple, 2 -> Hibiscus)

  val isPlant = ab2.forall((x) => x match {

    case (x: Int, p: Plant) => true
    case  _ => false
  })

  print(isPlant)
```

Output

```
Solution.scala:18: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0[Solution.Plant with Product with Serializable] cannot also be a Solution.Plant
    case (x: Int, p: Plant) => true
                     ^
one warning found
false
```

Edit: I could have caught this issue, if I had explicitly defined the type

```
 abstract class Living
  abstract class Animal extends Living
  abstract class Plant extends Living

  case class Dog() extends Animal
  case class Hibiscus() extends Plant
  case class Apple() extends Plant

  val ab1: Map[Int,Living]  = Map(1 -> Dog, 2 -> Hibiscus)
  val ab2: Map[Int,Living]  = Map(1 -> Apple, 2 -> Hibiscus)

  val isPlant = ab2.forall((x) => x match {

    case (x: Int, p: Plant) => true
    case  _ => false
  })

  print(isPlant)
```

Error:

```
Solution.scala:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Solution.Dog.type
 required: Solution.Living
  val ab1: Map[Int,Living]  = Map(1 -> Dog, 2 -> Hibiscus)
                                       ^
Solution.scala:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Solution.Hibiscus.type
 required: Solution.Living
  val ab1: Map[Int,Living]  = Map(1 -> Dog, 2 -> Hibiscus)
                                                 ^
Solution.scala:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Solution.Apple.type
 required: Solution.Living
  val ab2: Map[Int,Living]  = Map(1 -> Apple, 2 -> Hibiscus)
                                       ^
Solution.scala:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Solution.Hibiscus.type
 required: Solution.Living
  val ab2: Map[Int,Living]  = Map(1 -> Apple, 2 -> Hibiscus)
                                                   ^
four errors found
```

Comment: Thanks!! Answers by sepp2k and jorg are both informative. I'm choose the one by jorg as it explains why the warning. I upvoted comment by sepp2k as it adds the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatically generated companion `object` for a `case class` does *not* extend its companion `class` nor is it an instance of it.

In other words, the `Hibiscus` companion object does *not* extend `case class Hibiscus()` and is also not an instance of `case class Hibiscus()`, therefore it is also not an instance of `Fruit`.

Since `Hibiscus` is a constant, the compiler knows what type it will be at runtime, and warns you that it can never match the type you are testing for, and thus that branch of the pattern is unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

Your Map does not contain Plants. It contains functions that return Plants when called. You should either apply them by writing `Dog()` etc. in the Map or, better yet, define the plants as case objects instead of classes (so they don't need to be applied).